# What is the response to the criticism of LOP-G project by Zubrin and others?

Tags: space-station, future-missions, lunar-gateway

Many people have aired criticism of the project (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbital_Platform-Gateway#Criticisms) for some).

Was there any response from the project's team or NASA regarding these criticisms?

Comment: holding rallies and shouting "Space Force! Space Force!" and just generally confusing and subterfuging the public into submission. (see answers to [Why is the US building a Lunar Orbital Platform-Gateway (LOP-G)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30140/12102) and note the lack of an answer to [How will the Lunar Gateway go to L2 and L1?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30153/12102), or give a careful listen to this "word salad": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3ozOLbGXHI)

Comment: @uhoh - The deranged idea (25th amendment deranged!) of a Space Force is orthogonal to NASA.

Comment: @DavidHammen ha! yes indeed. still... https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30653/12102

Comment: I voted to close as "opinion based" because, as far as I can tell, NASA's response to criticism of the Lunar Orbital Platform - Gateway (formerly the Deep Space Gateway, but same thing) is crickets: It has no response to such criticisms. NASA doesn't respond to flat earthers, so why should it respond to Zubrin?

Comment: @DavidHammen adjusting the question to something like "Has there been any considered response to..." or "Have these objections been addressed in a systematic way" without restricting to a response by NASA might be a solution here? (incidentally, I think this is a thoughtful discussion about the other thing: https://youtu.be/iFOju7kuxMM?t=45)

Comment: @uhoh - NASA doesn't work that way. It is, and it has to be, responsive to the U.S. Congress and to the U.S. President. It is not responsive to the (sadly) large number of people in the U.S. who think the Earth is flat, nor is it responsive to the much, much smaller number of people who think that a ~20% delta V penalty to get to the surface of the Moon and back is a bad idea.

Comment: I tried to answer with "Crickets", which is 22 characters shy of a proper answer. But "crickets" (or "none") is the only possible answer, which is why I'm voting to close.

Comment: I think Zubrin is a big troll, he talks always very vehemently against the most beautiful, most effective space exploration projects. He is against anything what could elevete us above the current era dominated by few, from Earth launched rockets. I seriously doubt his goodwillingness.